# Color Two Cells Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cells

My code currently colors values in Range("N2:N86") anytime I insert a value in that range. However, I want to add an additional line of code that colors or highlights the preceding column Range("M2:M86") whenever a value is entered in Range("N2:N86").

So for example, if i put the value of 1 in N2, I want both N2 and M2 to be highlighted red. Thanks

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim inRng As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set myRng = Range("N2:N86")
myRng.Locked = True

If Range("R4") < 0 Then
    For Each rCell In myRng
        If rCell.Value > 0 Then
            If rRng Is Nothing Then
                Set rRng = rCell
            Else
                Set rRng = Application.Union(rRng, rCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    rRng.Locked = False
    rRng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

Comment: How about `rRng.Offset(0,-1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what you are asking for, but here's something that you can test. (Colors rows in both columns upon change in cell value in N column)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Range("N2:N86"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    Target.Offset(, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```